# Why am I getting "connection refused" error after restart Spark server?

Tags: junit, kotlin, integration-testing, spark-java

I have this test classes:

```
class PostIT {

    companion object {

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun initialise() {
            baseURI = "http://localhost:4567"
            Server.start()
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun tearDown() {
            Server.stop()
        }

    }

    //some test cases

}
```

---

```
class UserIT {

    companion object {

        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun initialise() {
            baseURI = "http://localhost:4567"
            Server.start()
        }

        @AfterClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun tearDown() {
            Server.stop()
        }

    }

    //some test cases

}
```

and `Server` object:

```
object Server {

    fun start() {
        Spark.init()
        prepareRoutes()
    }

    fun stop() {
        Spark.stop()
    }

    private fun prepareRoutes() {
        get("/users", whatever)
        //more routes
    }        

}
```

When I run both test classes separately, it works fine. But, when I tell IDE to run both test classes, I'm getting `connection refused error` when second test class is run.

It seems like when server is stopped, it never starts again. It's like `Spark.init()` is not working after server being stopped.

I've also tried calling `Spark.awaitInitialization()` after `Spark.init()`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Actually, problem wasn't the server initialization after stopped. We must wait until server is stopped. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451309/how-to-wait-until-spark-service-is-stopped).

```
fun stop() {
    try {
        Spark.stop()
        while (true) {
            try {
                Spark.port()
                Thread.sleep(500)
            } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
                break
            }

        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    }
}
```